# How to accentuate subtler traits (smaller numbers) in a heat map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I was trying to plot a heat map of these numbers:

```
[[0.578, 0.261, 0.218, 0.177, 0.128, 0.125, 0.119],
 [0.113, 0.111, 0.096, 0.095, 0.093, 0.088, 0.083],
 [0.081, 0.078, 0.077, 0.072, 0.071, 0.07, 0.07],
 [0.069, 0.068, 0.068, 0.067, 0.067, 0.06, 0.06],
 [0.059, 0.058, 0.058, 0.058, 0.056, 0.056, 0.056],
 [0.055, 0.055, 0.053, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051, 0.051],
 [0.05, 0.049, 0.048, 0.048, 0.048, 0.047, 0.047]]
```

As we can see, there is a tremendous difference betweeen the first number(0.578) and the last number(0.047). Hence, this is the heat map I am getting:

[image]

Here is the code that I used:

```
out_arr = np.asarray(x) ## x is the list of values that I mentioned above
a = out_arr
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
plt.imshow(x, cmap='plasma', aspect  ='auto')
plt.show()
```

My question is how can I bring about **greater contrast** in colour while not losing the **actual difference** in the numbers? For example, after the 2nd row, almost all others look similar. As I am looking to run Image recognition models on these heatmaps, a greater contrast will be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using different color maps?

Comment: Yes. I have tried 'cool' and 'hot' other than the plasma and both give similar results. Are there any other colours that could bring out these differences.

Comment: Also, will using some different library like seaborn help? Thanks!

Comment: Probably not, because the lower right values are very close to each other. You could apply a nonlinear transform like taking the square or even higher power, but obviously that will warp your data.

Comment: Hmm. Did not get what you meant by 'warp your data'. Does it imply that the essence of the data will be lost?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the [Colormap normalization tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html)

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is what I wanted. If I am able to implement it successfully, I'll answer the question myself:)

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the question. I could get the desired result, here's how:

Convert the list into a numpy array we can use:

```
import numpy as np
out_arr = np.asarray(x) 
a = out_arr
```

Then turn the standard heatmap into a logarithmic heat map:

```
import math
import seaborn as sn
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

data = a

log_norm = LogNorm(vmin=data.min().min(), vmax=data.max().max())
cbar_ticks = [math.pow(10, i) for i in range(math.floor(math.log10(data.min().min())), 1+math.ceil(math.log10(data.max().max())))]

sn.heatmap(
    data,
    cmap = 'plasma',
    norm=log_norm,
    cbar_kws={"ticks": cbar_ticks}
)
```

Here is a comparision with the originial heatmap and the new one -

**Original:**

[image]

**Modified:**

[image]

As can be seen, the modified hearmpa gives a much better colour variance.

PS: This is my first answer on SO, critique is welcomed. Also, thanks to
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest for pointing me in the right direction